# TypeError when updating Metaplex Nft, Cannot read 'toBuffer'

Tags: javascript, create-react-app, solana, metaplex

#### Program:

Metaplex-foundation/js(0.11.7)and Solana-Wallet-Adapter(0.9.16)
in Create-React-App 5

#### Preface:

I created a function to create a NFT

```
const createNFT = async() => {
const { nft } = await metaplex.nfts().create({
uri: "https://arweave.net/5bd58f4V4UEuTl1MGFX1dn1tu3dQTKWo7fCeZyEqQzc",

    })
    console.log(nft)
  }
```

Which worked fine creating my NFT, now I am trying to update the Metadata with this function

```
const _address = new PublicKey(address)

const updateMetadata = async() => {

    const { updatedNFT } = await metaplex.nfts().update({
        nftOrSft: _address,
        uri: "https://www.arweave.net/MuV4ddqdaqPzVGNOt89EW1v8bf4wh94ENCmxoZCYbN0?ext=json"
      })

  }
```

Also tried like this

```
        const { updatedNFT } = await metaplex.nfts().update(_address, {
            uri: "https://www.arweave.net/MuV4ddqdaqPzVGNOt89EW1v8bf4wh94ENCmxoZCYbN0?ext=json"
          })
```

#### Error:

```
findMetadataPda.ts:10 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toBuffer')
at findMetadataPda (findMetadataPda.ts:10:1)
at Object.handle (updateNft.ts:67:1)
at Task.callback (OperationClient.ts:66:1)
at Task.ts:82:1
at Disposable.run (Disposable.ts:34:1)
at Task.forceRun (Task.ts:74:1)
at Task.run (Task.ts:51:1)
at OperationClient.execute (OperationClient.ts:76:1)
at NftClient.update (NftClient.ts:80:1)
at updateMetadata (App.js:117:1)
```

Comment: r u using `@metaplex-foundation/js`

Comment: Yes I am @Yilmaz, also using solana-wallet-adapter as you can see in the top of the question and the corresponding versions.

Comment: did you conifgure webpack

Comment: The web application loads fine the problem I am having is when I run the onClick function I get this error in return, the docs say that it intakes a nft object; should I pass in the nft object returned from metaplex.findByMint() instead of the new PublicKey(address) @Yilmaz thank you also for taking the time out of your day to help

Comment: Okay nevermind that doesnt work either, returning the same error.

Comment: based on docs, pass the `nft` returned from `create()`

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is you are not overriding the webpack config: https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js-examples/tree/main/getting-started-react-cra5

> Copy the following code inside the new config-overrides.js file.

```
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = function override(webpackConfig) {
  // Disable resolving ESM paths as fully specified.
  // See: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/11467#issuecomment-691873586
  webpackConfig.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.m?js/,
    resolve: {
      fullySpecified: false,
    },
  });

  // Ignore source map warnings from node_modules.
  // See: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/11752
  webpackConfig.ignoreWarnings = [/Failed to parse source map/];

  // Polyfill Buffer.
  webpackConfig.plugins.push(
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ Buffer: ["buffer", "Buffer"] })
  );

  // Polyfill other modules.
  webpackConfig.resolve.fallback = {
    crypto: require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),
    stream: require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
    util: require.resolve("util"),
    assert: require.resolve("assert"),
    fs: false,
    process: false,
    path: false,
    zlib: false,
  };

  return webpackConfig;
};
```

then update your browser requirements shown in the link

Comment: I am actually using this example to run the code in

Comment: did you install `npm install react-app-rewired`

Comment: Yes, I meant like I actually git cloned the js-examples from metaplex then opened up getting-started-react-cra-5 and started from here. I have also passed the nft object of findByMint() => update and I am still returning same error, but it works for findByMint so I am lost on what the error is.

Comment: Nevermind we have fixed it together haha thank you very much I am going to update it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Yilmaz, there is an answer to this.

I had to pass it as an object like according to the docs it just wasnt clicking in my head haha.

Here is the code for others who may stumble upon this.

````
    const _address = new PublicKey(address);

    const fetchAndUpdateNft = async (e) => {
        const nftObject = await metaplex.nfts().findByMint(_address);
        console.log(nftObject)
        setNft(nftObject);
    
        const { nft: updatedNFT } = await metaplex.nfts().update(nftObject, {
          uri: "https://arweave.net/MuV4ddqdaqPzVGNOt89EW1v8bf4wh94ENCmxoZCYbN0?ext=json"
        });
        console.log(updatedNFT)
      }
    ```
````

Comment: Is there a reason why the json attr `image` is different from what's in the `files[0].uri`?

Comment: FYI, you must be using an old version of the SDK because the update operation should use the following signature: `await metaplex.nfts().update({ nftOrSft: nftObject, uri: '...' }).run();`.